# lambda equation in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++builder, c++builder-xe4

I would like to use lambda equation.
In the C++ Builder XE4, I tried the following.

```
#include <boost/mpl/lambda.hpp>

auto add = [] (int a, int b)-> int{ return a + b; };
```

However, I got "E2188: Expression syntax" error.

What is the problem?

I am sure that the boost library is correctly installed on my environment.

Comment: You need a C++11 compiler (like GCC 4.8 or Clang 3.3). Probably RadStudio is just an IDE (starting a command line compiler).

Comment: That's not a Boost lambda if that's what you were going for.

Comment: And is C++ Builder XE4 C++11 compatible? It has nothing to do with Boost, lambda expressions are a part of the core C++ language.

Comment: Thank you for all of you. I used C++ Builder XE4 for 32bit Windows7. From what you suggested, I checked the compatibility of lambda express in C++ Builder XE4. It seems that lambda equation is compatible for 64bit compiler not for 32bit (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/C%2B%2B11_Language_Features_Compliance_Status ). Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with code.
Compile with c++11.

```
auto add = [] (int a, int b)-> int{ return a + b; };
cout<<add(2,3);

http://ideone.com/PGSmXh
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found that the problem was not the sentence, but the compile environment which I have. I use C++ Builder XE4 on 32bit Windows (BCC32.exe). The BCC32 does not support lambda expression.

Comment: but BCC64 does, so you can play with that.

Comment: C++Builder 32bit will support c++11 next year.

Comment: Thank you Gregor Brandt. I will study on BCC64. Thank you mh taqia for the information. I am looking forward to using the new C++ Builder.